# glVertexAttribPointer() working only with the first stream

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I am trying to use glVertexAttribPointer() to give some data to my vertex shader. The thing is that it's working only with the FIRST attribute...

Here is my OpenGL code:

```
struct Flag_vertex
{
    GLfloat position_1[ 8 ];
    GLfloat position_2[ 8 ];
};

Flag_vertex flag_vertex;

   ... // fill some data to flag_vertex

GLuint vertexbuffer_id;
glGenBuffers( 1, &vertexbuffer_id );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer_id );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(flag_vertex), &flag_vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer_id );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)offsetof(Flag_vertex, position_1) );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)offsetof(Flag_vertex, position_2) );
```

and my shader is something like:

```
#version 420 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 in_position_1;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 in_position_2;

out vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(in_position_X, 0.0, 1.0);
    texcoord = in_position_X * vec2(0.5) + vec2(0.5);
}
```

If I use "in_position_1" my texture RENDERS PERFECTLY, but if I use in_position_2 nothing happens...

Tip: before link my shaders I am doing:

```
glBindAttribLocation( programID, 0, "in_position_1");
glBindAttribLocation( programID, 1, "in_position_2");
```

Why it works only with the first stream? I need more data going to my vertex... I need to send color, etc... any hint?

Comment: Have you enabled both vertex attributes?  BTW, you don't need to use the `glBindAttribLocation` if you use the layout qualifier in your shader.

Comment: Oh, yes, sure... I forgot to write... I do  glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 ) and glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 ) before use it... I will update it.

Comment: If you switch the layout ids (i.e., in_position_1 -> 1, in_position_2 -> 0), do things work differently?

Comment: kind of... if I switch them on the shader it stop working. if I switch the names on OpenGL code, the in_position_2 starts to work and the in_position_1 stops... it's like it only recognizes the first stream :-(

Comment: BTW, I tried with an without the "layout(location = X)" and it has the same result.

Comment: Hmmm ... everything that's here looks okay.  Any GL errors?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23319/discussion-between-radical7-and-wagner-patriota)

Answer (score 0):

```
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)offsetof(Flag_vertex, position_1) );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)offsetof(Flag_vertex, position_2) );
```

These lines don't make sense. At least, not with how `Flag_vertex` is defined. If `Flag_vertex` is really supposed to be a *vertex* (and not a quad), then it makes no sense for it to have 8 floats. If each `Flag_vertex` defines a full quad, then you named it wrong; it's not a *vertex* at all, it's `Flag_quad`.

So it's hard to know what you're even trying to accomplish here.

Also:

> If I use "in_position_1" my texture RENDERS PERFECTLY, but if I use in_position_2 nothing happens...

Of course it does. Your position data is in attribute 0. Your position data is therefore *not* in attribute 1. If you pretend attribute 1 has your position data when it clearly doesn't, you will not get reasonable results.

Your problem is that you're always using attribute 0 when you should be using *both of them.* You shouldn't be picking one or the other. Use `in_position_1` for the position and `in_position_2` for the texture coordinate. And try to name them reasonably, based on what they do (like `position` and `texture_coord` or something). Don't use numbers for them.

> Tip: before link my shaders I am doing:

That is the exact same thing as the `layout(location=#)` setting in the shader. If you want it in the shader, then put it in the shader. If you want it in your OpenGL code, then put it in your OpenGL code. Don't put it in both places.

Comment: Actually, the `glVertexAttribPointer` calls in the OP are perfectly fine; they merely place the two streams of attribute data sequentially in the VBO.  It's a very common way of using data in VBOs.  
The resolution of the problem was in another place in the OP's code, and nothing related to the OP. Please see the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23319/discussion-between-radical7-and-wagner-patriota) above for the resolution.

Comment: @radical7: "*they merely place the two streams of attribute data sequentially in the VBO*" But "attribute data" is not **a** "vertex". Which was my point: if it was intended to be two non-interleaved arrays in one struct, then the struct is improperly named.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm failing to understand your point.  If you're commenting on the variable names chosen by the poster, that's irrelevant to the solution.  The code in the post is correct and consistent (and nicely formatted to boot :)  In fact, all of the code in the OP is correct - the problem was elsewhere in the OP's application.

Comment: Yes, the problem was elsewhere... the code above is perfect. Thank you all for the contribution.